# Options for caching large datasets in browser for local development

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm creating a library for our company's internal use that could be used to develop JS-based data dashboards. The system loads a dataset from an API and displays visualisations of it in the browser. The datasets used might be up to 100MB in size.

When doing local development with this system, it currently re-downloads the data each time the page is refreshed, which slows down local development considerably. Ideally upon refresh, the library would only compare latest changed timestamps with the API and use a locally cached version in case they match.

Javascript's `localStorage` would be ideal for this, but unfortunately it has a limit of 5MB. So is there an alternative that could be used to store larger data? Or can I extend the `localStorage` somehow? Since this library is only for internal use, I'm okay with altering browser configurations and installing browser plugins, if that is necessary.

Comment: You could use Electron to make a desktop app and access the computer filesystem

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of data! It's probably not ideal to be loading in this much data to the browser, and there isn't a way to increase the size of localStorage. I would suggest trying to implement a service worker. Alternatively, you could use GraphQL to make more efficient queries, in turn minimising the amount of data needed to be sent.